# What is the meaning of Attachments size in CodeCloud repo dashboard

Tags: git, bitbucket

What is the meaning of Attachments size and how it differs from the other size?

[image]

Comment: I would guess / speculate that you are allowed to upload nearly one gigabyte of data at once. but did you consider the manual?

Comment: I can't find any documentation regarding the Attachments size and what it could possible mean.